# Strange black box appearing in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

[image]

Hi!

I am new in wpf application development. I just create a demo application and I see that the black box appearing in the top of my application. Can anyone tell me how can I remove this ?

I am sorry, I don't even know the name of it.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This is a new feature as of VS 2015 Update 2 [XAML Diagnostics](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#misc). 
This shows up only if you are debugging the application.

If you really need to disable this, there's an option in the Tools > Options > Debugging > General - Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML > Show runtime tools in application

[image: XAML UI runtime tools options]

Comment: Meh, I've been without it for years now. I see no need in it. (For me of course, someone else could find it useful) It's just an annoyance. Thanks for showing how to disable it.

Comment: 'only debugging'.. it shows up when i run it as 'Release' too.

Comment: This feature does not work with Managed Compatibility mode on.

Comment: @ShawnKovac What Petr means by "only debugging" is doing Debug/Start Debugging (aka F5) as opposed to Debug/Start Without Debugging (aka Ctrl-F5), not Debug vs Release configurations

Comment: it would be more helpful if it can be dragged elsewhere.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue, ah! now that makes sense! thanks, mate!

Comment: Thanks. This window is so annoying. Always obscures what you're trying to see and you can't drag it.

Comment: Note that this is now referred to by microsoft as "Hot Reloading" and now has its own section under Debugging in Options.

Comment: Options --> Debugging --> Hot Reload --> Enable in-app toolbar (in WPF and UWP section)

Answer (score 13):

This is new (and, actually, useful) feature in VS 2015 Update 2 (In-App Menu).
It allows you to pick visuals directly from the screen and switch to visual tree viewer (see "Live Visual Tree" toolbox).

It affects debug mode only.

Comment: How does this differ from  using Snoop?  I've been using that for debugging bindings and styles in WPF for a while now, is there any reason to switch or use them both side by side?

Comment: It's not much different than snoop, it's just now built in to VS and doesn't need to be run standalone.

Answer (score 6):

As the others have said it is a UI Debugger and can be very helpful. You don't need to go to the options menu to disable this though. There is a button that toggles it on and off in the Live Visual Tree tab.

See image [UI Debugger toggle - visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4qzF.png)

Comment: Thanks, Aech!! This is great alternative to permanent disable.