# WPF inspector Tool that doesn't require .net 3.5

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am looking for a WPF Diagnostic tool like Snoop or WPF inspector that doesn't require .NET 3.5, because I am unable to install .NET 3.5 on my device.
It would be great if somebody knows a simular Tool that runs with an actual .NET Version or knows how to get run snoop with the actual .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

There would be probably no tool better than Xamarin Inspector,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/inspector/

Answer (score 1):

The latest [Visual Studio 2015 update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#misc) provides such tool, here is an official blog entry about it:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/06/ui-development-made-easier-with-xaml-edit-continue/

[image]

Just in case you wish to disable the feature, you can do it in the Debug settings like explained in this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468509/strange-black-box-appearing-in-wpf-application).