# Closing a window throws a InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window in which I handle the Closing event in a custom function. In the XAML I have set the following:

```
<ext:ExtendedWindow x:Name="Window1" Closing="Window_Closing">
```

This function is declared in the code-behind as follows:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Closing -= Window_Closing;
        e.Cancel = true;
        Storyboard storyboard = this.CloseWindowWidthAnimation(0f);
        storyboard.Completed += CloseWindow;
        storyboard.Begin();

    }

    private void CloseWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Window_Closing cancels the closing event and plays an animation on the window (width shrinks to 0). To the Completed event I add a function that finally closes the window after the animation has played. CloseWindowWidthAnimation is a static method in a helper class that just returns a storyboard. The ExtendedWindow has a base class of Window and only has a few dependencyproperties to handle color schemes.

When the Close function is done executing and Just My Code is enabled, the 'break mode' screen pops up. Continuing the debugging session exits the application, but I think this is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104485/the-application-is-in-break-mode-1.html). When Just My Code is disabled, the following error shows:

```
This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource.
```

The error shows **when the window has in fact been closed** after CloseWindow exits. I do think it has something to do with the storyboard/animation, since it does not throw the error when I don't override the Closing event. When I build the app and run the executable, it doesn't crash and I don't catch the error somewhere. I'm thinking it has something to do with the storyboard, but the error isn't very descriptive and I haven't been able to find anything on this. So my question is as follows:

What might cause this type of behaviour? What could I possibly do to fix this?

Update: Call Stack window (Main thread)

[image: Call Stack window]

Comment: You need to show us the content of the Debug > Windows > Call Stack window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468509/strange-black-box-appearing-in-wpf-application

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why you might be linking that post. My question has nothing to do with the XAML diagnostic tool, and the error is encountered after the window has closed (added clarification) so there aren't any elements I could inspect.